# How can I add different objects in array at the same time and store them for the next move?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and working on game project for my finals. I am trying to add different values to my array but when I print array every time it shows different objects on the map I will share the output here.
This is the main class:

```java
import MAP.*;
import Person.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map map = new Map();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person character = new Person("ahmet");
        Person npc = new Person("mehmet");
        npc.placeObject();
        character.setPosX(character.random1);
        character.setPosY(character.random2);
        character.placeCharacter(character.posX, character.posY);

        System.out.println(character.name);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <5 ;i++) {

            String a = sc.nextLine();
            character.MoveCharacter(a);

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

This is my Person class:

```java
import MAP.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class Person extends Map {

    public int posX;
    public int posY;


    public int getPosX(Random rnd){
        return posX;
    }
    public int getPosY(){
        return posY;
    }
    public void setPosX(int posX){
        this.posX=posX;
        System.out.println(posX);
    }
    public void setPosY(int posY){
        this.posY=posY;
        System.out.println(posY);
    }
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person(String name,int posX,int posY) {
        this.name = name;
        this.posX= posX;
        this.posY= posY;
    }  
    public void placeCharacter(int x, int y){
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        gameMap[b[x]][a[y]] = "⚫";
        showMap();
    }
}
```

This is my Map class:

```java
package MAP;

import Person.Person;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Random;

public class Map {
    public String[][] gameMap = {
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
                { "|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|","|"," ","|",},
                { "+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+","+---+",},
    };
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public int random1 = rnd.nextInt(9);
    public int random2 = rnd.nextInt(9);
    public int [] a={1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28};
    public int [] b={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
    public String tree="+";
    public void placeObject(){
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
            int random3 = rnd.nextInt(5);
            if (random3 < 3) {
                int random1 = rnd.nextInt(9);
                int random2 = rnd.nextInt(9);
                gameMap[b[random1]][a[random2]] = tree;
                System.out.println(random1 + " " + random2);
            }
            if(i==9)
                showMap();
        }
    }
    public void showMap() {
        for (int r=0; r<gameMap.length; r++){
            for (int c=0; c<gameMap[r].length; c++){
                System.out.print(gameMap[r][c]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

One of my friend told me to extract the map but I dont know what should I do exactly.
these are objects
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aaem.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Hk0.png)

Comment: Please share the main code that you run . Also you class links are strange, how a Person **is** a Map (you used extension) ?

Comment: I shared the main but the problem is placing and storing the objets so I didnt shared the move methods.

Comment: you should not use commonly used classes or interfaces as names of your classes. Since Map is a common interface for a collection of entries, you should name your own Map sth. like AreaMap. This reduces confusion..

Answer (score 0):

Why does `Person extends Map`? That implies that every Person IS a Map, and furthermore that each person has its own INDIVIDUAL copy of every field inside of the `Map` class, including `gameMap`. Instead, you should pass the map you instantiate in the main method to each person as a *constructor parameter*, and have `map` be a field of `Person`.

```
public Person(String name, int posX, int posY, Map map) {
    this.name = name;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.map = map;
}
```